# creating border for uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using a uitableview and scrollview in a uiview. How to set a border for table or scrollview?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
#import  "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

then in `viewDidLoad` use,

```
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

**Note**

You can also set the border color:

```
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

It should work for you. :)

Comment: There's also a tableView.layer.borderColor property (CGColorRef) as you might expect.

Comment: tableView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor].  This also works

Answer (score 10):

This works quite well for me:

```
CALayer *layer = _tableView.layer;
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius: 4.0];
[layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.8 alpha: 1.0] CGColor]];
```

The rounded borders look a little more iOS.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can we add a button to the layer so it shows up in front?

Answer (score 3):

> if you want to give the border to tableview with color, use below code
>   for swift 3

```
yourTableViewName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
yourTableViewName.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```