# How do I change the color of a UITableView border?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UITableView in a UISplitViewController and I have a custom header cell at the top of that table view.  The custom header view has a dark grey background image set in it, but the problem is the left side of the header cell shows a light grey border (circled in red in the image below)...

[image]

How can I change that color or get rid of that border?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: It looks like your table view is not positioned correctly.

Comment: If you zoom in on your screenshot, you will see that the vertical white line goes all the way down the image.  Move your whole table view one point to the left.

Comment: Yes, the "x" location of the tableview was 1. Thank you! How do I accept a comment as the answer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`
In ViewDidLoad use,

```
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283041/creating-border-for-uitableview) too.

Comment: dont forget to add quratzcore to you project